# iOS: make an app unresponsive using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to make an app unresponsive to **all** gestures, motion etc. until instructed otherwise?

For example, if an app responds to shake gestures and has a few buttons, is there a *global* property that I can trigger that makes the app unresponsive to all of these, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you keep a flag (preferably stored in NSUserDefaults) and check it every time when the relevant gesture is fired. If the flag is true let the function execute else just leave it as it is.

Comment: No, I don't think there is a global "ignore the user" flag. You'd have to add custom code in various places. For touches, you could do as llb suggests in their answer, but then you'd have to also add code to ignore shake gestures, and if you had code that used the accelerometer directly you'd have to add "ignore the user" logic there as well.

Comment: Why would you ever want this? I would uninstall this in 0 time, flat.

Comment: @DuncanC Sure -- I'll just patch in custom code and keep a flag running. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Alexander When a user presses a button say, I want a sequence of events (or animations) to happen before the user can press that button again to re-trigger than sequence of events.

Comment: As Alexander says, this sounds like a bad user experience. Locking up the UI is likely to annoy your users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

But please, don't do it. I believe your problem has better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Perhaps I'll keep a flag to represent this instead.